# Why when adding Data Source to Google Data Studio is it added to Google Drive?

Tags: looker-studio

Why when adding Data Source to Google Data Studio is it added to Google Drive? I downloaded this file from Google Drive. Its size is 0. I deleted it from Google Drive. And then I uploaded this file back to Google Drive from my hard drive. But Google Data Studio doesn’t see this Data Source. Why is the Data Source then added to Google Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Studio uses Drive to store data sources to simplify the sharing & access model. By using drive, it's easy to collaborate on both reports & data sources and easily control access. See [Share and collaborate](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6283323?hl=en#share-and-collaborate) for more information.